# How can I sort entries by a custom field in the CP, Craft 3?

Tags: control-panel, sorting

I have an events section with a custom field of eventDate and it would be very helpful to editors to have them listed in event date order.
In Craft 2 I used the plugin [CP Sortable Custom Columns](https://github.com/mmikkel/CpSortableCustomColumns-Craft) by Mikkel Rummelhoff but he hasn't ported it to Craft 3 and may not, he says.

I would have thought this option would be useful to many people, so has anyone got any suggestions as to how to achieve it, I'm not a plugin developer myself.

Comment: I just went through this same issue and it's not currently possible in Craft 3. Ideally this would be a native abilitiy, but if not a plugin would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Craft 3.2 beta](https://craftcms.com/blog/craft-3-2-beta-released) adds support sortable custom fields.

Answer (score 2):

A few solutions:

1. Hire someone to create a plugin for you
2. Learn PHP in order to include the ability to sort those fields
3. Create  a feature request and hope Pixel and Tonic will include it

For those who want to sort entries by custom fields can [read the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#modifyentrysortableattributes-modifycategorysortableattributes-modifyassetsortableattributes-modifyusersortableattributes) in order to get to know how it is possible

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_REGISTER_SORT_OPTIONS, function(RegisterElementSortOptionsEvent $event) {
    $event->sortOptions[] = [
        'orderBy' => 'content.field_eventDate', //<-- content. + handle of the field prefixed with field_ to match the database column
        'label' => 'My Awesome custom search',// <-- name of the label in the CP
        'attribute' => 'field:10' //<--- id of your field
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robin.
1. I'd rather not have a custom plugin created for me as maintaining it going forward is likely to be an issue.
2. I'm struggling to keep up with the amount of new code I need to learn for Craft 3 already, as well as the constant changes of development envirionment.
3. I've added a comment to the existing feature request.